# opening several terminals at once

Tags: macos, terminal, shell-script, bash-scripting

In my dev environment, I sometimes need several terminals to be open, each running its own script/ a server (rails, django, redis, mongo, consoles, etc)

How can I create some shortcut that will open terminals, each with it's own script, at once (instead of opening new terminals and writing these commands by hand?)

running os x 10.9

Answer (score 0):

The following command

```
 (xterm -e "/path/to/my/script; bash" &); (xterm -e "/path/to/my/other/script; bash") &
```

opens two xterms' which execute the two scripts (provided they have been made executable, of course), and then wait for further instructions. You can easily build an alias to it, or put it into a script accepting the two paths of the two scripts as arguments.

EDIT

If you have a file of commands, one per line, called *mycommands.txt*, you can execute each one of them by means of the following one-liner:

```
  for i in `seq 1 $(cat mycommands.txt | wc -l)`; do (xterm -e "awk 'NR == $i' mycommands.txt; bash" &)  ; done
```

Again, this can easily be aliased, or scripted.

Comment: so I need each one liner script to be in a file of its own? Is it possible to have one script file that will do all commands each in a new window?

Comment: @NickGinanto Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an Applescript like this:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "/path/to/my/script"
    do script "/path/to/my/script-2"
    ...
    do script "/path/to/my/script-n"
    activate
end tell
```

This will open a new Terminal window per script.